# Django Runtime Error: calling method in __init__ causes maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, initialization, infinite-loop, django-errors

I want to call `password_generator` method when `Register` class is instantiated and assign the value return from from the method to `password` field.

When the register object is instantiated, why do I get

> RuntimeError at /register/
>
> maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

This is the code

**models.py**

```
class Register(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    password = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    firstname= models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.password = Register().password_generator()

    #Generate random login password for candidate
    def password_generator(self, size=30, chars=string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(size))
```

Logs from the terminal

**console**

```
  File "D:\Project\Online-Examination-System\register\models.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.password = Register().password_generator()
  File "D:\Project\Online-Examination-System\register\models.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.password = Register().password_generator()
  File "D:\Project\Online-Examination-System\register\models.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.password = Register().password_generator()
  File "D:\Project\Online-Examination-System\register\models.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.password = Register().password_generator()
  File "D:\Project\Online-Examination-System\register\models.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.password = Register().password_generator()
  File "D:\Project\Online-Examination-System\register\models.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.password = Register().password_generator()
  File "D:\Project\Online-Examination-System\register\models.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.password = Register().password_generator()
  File "D:\Project\Online-Examination-System\register\models.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.password = Register().password_generator()
  File "D:\Project\Online-Examination-System\register\models.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.password = Register().password_generator()
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, I came to realize that the function that I'm trying to call is in infinite loop. To access `password_generator()` method, I have to do `Register().password_generator()`. So that's also means `__init__` method is called- because of `Register()`. In the `__init()__`, I again call `Register()`. This is why it becomes an infinite loop. To solve this, we have to use:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.password = self.password_generator()
```